# Extracting the coordinates from Google Map URL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-maps

I have been experimenting with C# trying to create a Windows Form that has a web browser component with the following initial URL:

```
 queryAddress.Append("https://www.google.com/maps/place/Costa+Rica/&output=embed");
 wbGMap.Navigate(queryAddress.ToString());
```

I looked here and in other site in hopes to find a way to save the latitude and longitude values of a location. For example if I search on the map for X Hotel using the build in search of the map I would like to get those coordinates and with a button event display them on a text field each. Yet the only solution I have found so far are over complicated google API.

Is there a simple way for just extracting those two values for later use?

Thanks a lot in advance for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: If I enter that Url I get redirected to a new url with latitude and longitude in plain text as part of the url, Just grab it and show it? (https://www.google.com/maps/place/Costa+Rica/@10.3118691,-84.2370058,6z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x8f92e56221acc925:0x6254f72535819a2b)

Comment: Quite so, but I don't want to show the whole URL just the part concerning to lat/long. Like trimming from google to @ and from z/... onwards.

Comment: Just grab the current Url of the web browser control, get the coordinates and display them in your visible TextBox. Hide the Url textbox if you have one. If you are asking how to trim out the values thats basic string manipulation with IndexOf, Substring, Split,

Comment: Alright I'll look intot hose last things. thanks

Comment: If you never did any string manipulations before it is highly recommended to do this. You learn something basic and important. If you want to go to a higher level look into Regex. 

Comment: I'll take that to heart, indeed I am not familiar with this topic I just knew it must be doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheat sheet for when you've played with string manipulation:

```
string url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Costa+Rica/@10.3118691,-84.2370058,6z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x8f92e56221acc925:0x6254f72535819a2b";
int pos1 = url.IndexOf("/@");
string rightpart = url.Substring(pos1+("/@".Length));
int pos2 = rightpart.IndexOf("/");
string coords = rightpart.Substring(0, pos2);
var split = coords.Split(',');
var lat = split[0];
var lon = split[1];
var zzz = split[2];
```

or the advanced Regex version:

```
string url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Costa+Rica/@10.3118691,-84.2370058,6z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x8f92e56221acc925:0x6254f72535819a2b";
var match = Regex.Match(url, @"http.*/@(?<lat>-?\d*\.\d*),(?<lon>-?\d*\.\d*),(?<zzz>\d*z).*");
var lat2 = match.Groups["lat"].Value;
var lon2 = match.Groups["lon"].Value;
var zzz2 = match.Groups["zzz"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Costa+Rica/@10.3118691,-84.2370058,6z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x8f92e56221acc925:0x6254f72535819a2b"
str_extract(url,'\\d+\\.\\d+\\,\\-\\d+\\.\\d+') %>% str_split(',') %>% unlist()
# [1] "40.7540123"  "-73.9841851"
```

Comment: You really should explain your code. Also, maybe you didn't realize, but this question is 4 years old.